xml: define data type of attribute value by separate attribute
I am trying to validate the value of an attribute against a data type that is defined via another attribute in the same xml document. E.g:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <element value="12" datatype="int" />
    <element value="hello" datatype="str" />
    <element value="hello" datatype="int" />
</root>

I found some help here and here and tried some more along the lines of this but for one the first two links seem contradictory and also I couldn't really map the examples to my use case. How would I achieve that in the xsd?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="datatype" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="int" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="float" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="str" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="bool" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:key name="dtype_key">
                        <xs:selector xpath="element" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@datatype" />
                    </xs:key>
                    <xs:keyref name="dtype_ref" refer="dtype_key">
                        <xs:selector xpath="element" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@value" />
                    </xs:keyref>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

I'd expect the validation to fail for the third element...
Thanks in advance.
